# Weakly supervised learning and missing labels for data that likely contains that label

Tags: machine-learning, multilabel, semi-supervised-learning

I would like to know how to deal with data that misses a label, but is likely to contain the label in a weakly supervised setting.

## Weakly supervised background

Since labeling is a time consuming and noisy process (e.g. Should a timestamp of an event be at 5.4 or 5.5 seconds?), some people instead take a weakly labelled approach. This approach only provides a label for the whole recording. E.g. an audio file contains events x, y, z without any temporal information for each time stamp.
A database containing weak labels is the [YouTube-8M database](https://research.google.com/youtube8m/).

The first 2 chapters of the paper [Data-Efficient Weakly Supervised Learning for Low-Resource Audio Event Detection Using Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06972) does a good job describing the issue.

## Problem description

I'm turning Mozilla's [Common Voice](https://voice.mozilla.org/en) dataset into a weakly supervised dataset. I do this by concatenating audio files (4+-3 seconds) into 10 second files. Then as output label for the whole 10 sec audio file I say it contains e.g. the accent labels `["eng_us", "eng_england", "eng_australia"]`. If I want to recognize 5 English accents, I would e.g. encode this into `[1 0 1 1 0]` (with the other 2 being e.g. `["eng_indian", "eng_scotland"]`.

Due to user's not always specifying their information, such as "gender", "accent" and such, the data might miss the label `"eng_england"`, while it is clearly in the voice data. Unlike the YouTube-8M, where I assume that a video containing e.g. an explosion, but not labeled as such is rather small, in the common voice dataset it is a high amount. E.g. `"Gender"` has `55.029 "male"`, `18.249 "female"`, `781 "other"`, `121.717 "NaN"`.

## Question

- What is the best way to encode the labels for these concatenated audio files?
- If a value is `NaN`, would it be better to take a soft labeling approach i.e. `[0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2]`?
- Would a concatenated file with labels `[0 0 1 1 0]` give a problem, while it should actually have been `[1 0 1 1 0]`, because person A didn't say he/she has an `"eng_us"` accent?